# Как передать ассемблерную инструкцию функции "asm" через параметр модуля ядра?

Tags: c, linux, ассемблер, kernel

*добавлено из комментария:* В Си есть функция [asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), с помощью которой можно делать ассемблерные вставки. Как я понимаю, эта функция принимает строки и преобразует их в команды. Мне нужно, чтобы выполнялась команда, которую я передам модулю в качестве параметра.

Я пробовал сделать через указатель `char*`, принимающий параметр с помощью `module_param()`, но компилятор выдает ошибку:

> "Expected string literal before..."

Comment: @Abyx в си есть функция asm, с помощью которой можно делать ассемблерные вставки. Как я понимаю, эта функция принимает строки и преобразует их в команды. Мне нужно, чтобы выполнялась команда, которую я передам модулю в качестве параметра

Comment: @Edward Dankovsky asm - это костыль GCC, в Си такого нет. Этот "костыль" вставляет в указанные программистом места ассемблерные инструкции. Единственно что можно передать, это адрес метки по которой эти инструкции расположены, ещё и их длину, если вычислив разность двух меток.

Comment: @dsnk, asm - это ключевое слово, определённое стандартом.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов каким стандартом? можно ссылку на официальный ресурс?

Comment: @dsnk, стандартом языка Си. Можно. J.5.10. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: @АнтонСазонов это плохой стандарт, например: как стандартные инструкции x86 будут на ARM выполняться?

Comment: @dsnk что значит "плохой стандарт"? Тогда где взять хороший? Делая такие ("asm - это костыль GCC") заявления ты руководствуешься чем-то кроме личных убеждений? Синтаксис не определён стандартом, по этому последний вопрос не имеет права на ответ.

Comment: @АнтонСазонов руководствуюсь переносимостью кода, а не данью моде и стандартам где кое-что не стандартизовано.

Comment: @dsnk, твои заявления ни на чём не основаны.

Comment: @dsnk, поскольку GCC есть почти везде, то можно ведь его и считать стандартом (хотя бы для себя) и писать именно на нем (а если кого-то такой код не устраивает, то он может (если сможет) такой код переписать как ему нравится)

Comment: @avp А при смене платформы, опять переписать? тогда зачем "гадание на кофейной гуще" назвали стандартом? В Си есть что улучшать, но этому религиозному спору тут не место.

Comment: @dsnk, конечно, переписать (добавить новую платформу ifdef-ами). Вообще, чем чаще программа переписывается, тем лучше она становится.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых как вам правильно сказали `asm` нестандартный, это плюшка GCC. Во-вторых `asm` это не функция это такое расширение компилятора. Но главное, что его агрументом должен быть строковый литерал, то есть `asm` только захардкоженый текст "принимает", а указатели на строку не принимает. Собственно текст ошибки вам об этом и сообщает.

Зато можно передавать ассемблерному коду [параметры из рантайма](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm):

```
 int src = 1;
 int dst;

 asm("mov %1, %0\n\t"
     "add $1, %0"
        : "=r" (dst)
        : "r"  (src)  );

 printf("%d\n", dst);
```

Comment: А есть способ передать параметр в виде строкового литерала? В том смысле, чтобы я мог через параметр, переданный модулю, выполнить произвольную команду

Comment: придется писать свой "миликомпилятор". Хотя можно и gcc приручить,пусть он преобразовывает asm код в бинарный, а модуль ядра уже будет исполнять. Вот только тут поработать нужно будет хорошо.

Comment: @EdwardDankovsky Вы видимо jit хотите сделать. Тогда следует использовать соответсвующие инструменты libjit, llvm... много вариантов есть.